# Flutter (Dart) Looping through JSON results - .length returns 0

Tags: json, dart, flutter, aqueduct

I'm new to flutter and after some good progress got stuck on what i though should be a simple loop. I'm able to show a single result from the json, but unable to display them all.

```
for(var i = 0; i < snapshot.data.posts.length; i++){
  return Text(snapshot.data.posts[i].name + " - " + snapshot.data.posts[i].id  + " - " + i.toString());
}
```

As this coded returns and outputs the first result of the dataset.

```
Mr. Nice - 1 - 0
```

The problems is that i can can't get it to output the rest of the results in the dataset. The external JSON which i'm parsing reads as follows (in full)

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Mr. Nice"},{"id":2,"name":"Narco"},{"id":3,"name":"Bombasto"},{"id":4,"name":"Celeritas"},{"id":5,"name":"Magneta"},{"id":6,"name":"Super Adueduct"},{"id":7,"name":"Mr. Test"}]
```

This full flutter page (which has been separated into it's own route) is as follows:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Future<PostsList> fetchPostsList() async {
  final response =
    await http.get('http://localhost:8888/heroes');

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return PostsList.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load post');
    }
  }

  class PostsList {
    final List<Post> posts;
    PostsList({
      this.posts,
    });

    factory PostsList.fromJson(List<dynamic> parsedJson) {

    List<Post> posts = new List<Post>();
    posts = parsedJson.map((i)=>Post.fromJson(i)).toList();

    return new PostsList(
      posts: posts
    );
  }
}

class Post{
  final String id;
  final String name;

  Post({
    this.id,
    this.name
  });

  factory Post.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
    return new Post(
      id: json['id'].toString(),
      name: json['name'],
    );
  }
}

class HeroesPage extends StatelessWidget {
 @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return MaterialApp(
       title: 'Fetch Data Example',

       home: Scaffold(
         appBar: AppBar(
           title: Text('Fetch Data Example'),
         ),

       body: Center(
         child: FutureBuilder<PostsList>(
           future: fetchPostsList(),

           builder: (context, snapshot) {
             if (snapshot.hasData) {

               for(var i = 0; i < snapshot.data.posts.length; i++){
                 return Text(snapshot.data.posts[i].name + " - " + 
                 snapshot.data.posts[i].id  + " - " + i.toString());
               }
               //return Text(snapshot.data.posts[1].name);
               } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                 return Text("${snapshot.error}");
               }

               // By default, show a loading spinner
               return CircularProgressIndicator();
               },
             ),
           ),
         ),
       );
     }
```

Now i may be going about displaying simple api data all wrong, it's just hard to find a non-firebase tutorial working with flutter and api's.

FYI - The API running on localhost was set-up with Aqueduct by following this tutorial: https://aqueduct.io/docs/tut/getting-started/

The code and classed where based on the Flutter docs tutorial (yet slightly modified for my json structure): https://flutter.io/cookbook/networking/fetch-data/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're really close! The problem is that return in your for loop inside the FutureBuilder `builder` function. The return breaks out of the loop after the first iteration, so you'll only ever get the first element of your data.

Instead, you need to generate a list of all widgets in the data and *then* return the list.

Two possible ways I can think to solve this (depends on your desired display widget):

=> Use a [ListView.builder](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/ListView/ListView.builder.html) to handle the iteration for you:

```
if (snapshot.hasData) {
  List<Post> yourPosts = snapshot.data.posts;
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: yourPosts.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        // Whatever sort of things you want to build
        // with your Post object at yourPosts[index]:
        return Text(yourPosts[index].toString());
      }
    );
  }
```

=> Build a `List<Widget>` and return a column (closest to your original approach):

```
if (snapshot.hasData) {
  List <Widget> myPosts;
  for(var i = 0; i < snapshot.data.posts.length; i++){
    myPosts.add(Text(snapshot.data.posts[i].name + " - " + 
      snapshot.data.posts[i].id  + " - " + i.toString())
    );
  }
  return Column( children: myPosts );
}
```